# Tzipita Lishua in English online

Tags: jewish-books, internet, messianic-redemption

Do we have the book "Tzipita Lishua" by Rabbi Israel Meir Kagan ZT"L online in english?

Comment: What is there to downvote about??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find it online [on this page](https://www.scribd.com/doc/19090647/Kuntres-Sfat-Tamim-Tzipitah-LeYeshuah?secret_password=pcdj71ph3ifyuafw0tl).

Comment: How is this answer different from the previous one?

Comment: The previous one said "it's not online" (incorrectly), and this answer says "it's online" (correctly). HTH.

Comment: I might be misinterpreting the question, but I thought OP was looking for the text online, not for a place to order it from.

Comment: @DonielF The text is online, at the link I provided. You can order a hard copy from that page but you can also read an online copy at the same page. I really don't get what's so complicated about this.

Comment: Ah, I see now. If it’s all the same to you, I edited your post so that it includes a direct link to the text.

Comment: I am not able to download it

Comment: How do I download it?

Answer (score 2):

There is facing translation with the original Hebrew as well. Both hard copy and online.

https://chafetzchayim.org/product/kuntres-sfat-tamim-tzipitah-leyeshuah/

Comment: Thanks for the resource, although I don't think this answers the question.

Comment: The question was for an online version.

Comment: It's literally online on that page.

Comment: @Gabriel I think you know that online version means the book is readable in it's entirety online.

Comment: @Robev The book *is* readable in *its entirety online. On that very page. Scroll down the page. You'll find the entire book there.

Comment: I was incorrect it is online as well, I made an edit to reflect that. Thank you Gabriel.